# Is there anyway to access and edit Cron Jobs from a C# application?

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, cron

I've got a C# asp.net core app running on an Ubuntu box. I need to run some scheduled tasks and wanted some way to manage that from the app, rather than logging into a terminal.

Is there anyway the C# app can connect to cron and return current jobs, add / edit existing ones?

Comment: From my limited knowledge, CRON-jobs are stored on file-system at `/var/spool/cron/` or `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. You could probably read them from the filesystem and edit them as you want. You can also run new bash commands from your application code to read out the cron jobs using `crontab -l`.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to expand on the following code:

```
    Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();

    Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.Start();
```

This will get you started with executing bash commands and reading the output in your code.

Alternatively, as Tristan mentioned in the comments, you can certainly read/write the cron files from your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but if you want a controllable scheduled tasks you can consider using [hosted services to perform background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) or libraries/frameworks like [`Hangfire`](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire) or [Quartz.NET](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet).